# Getting from $Y-A = U \cap Y$ to $A = (X-U) \cap Y$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm having a bit of trouble with the set algebra in this proof, I have a feeling it's something quite simple but I'm just not seeing it. That if $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, then $A \subseteq Y$ is closed if and only if $A$ equals the intersection of a closed set of $X$ with $Y$.

So for the forward direction, we assume that $A$ is closed in $Y$. Thus $Y-A$ is open in $Y$, and thus can be written as $Y-A = U \cap Y$ where $U$ is an open set of $X$.

The part that I'm a bit stuck is getting from

$$Y-A = U \cap Y$$

means $$A = Y \cap (X-U)$$

It's easy to prove with double set containment arguments but I'm just not getting the set algebra manipulations I need.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A\subseteq Y$,

$$A=Y\setminus(Y\setminus A)=Y\setminus(U\cap Y)=Y\setminus U=Y\cap(X\setminus U)\;.$$

The second equality is just substituting from what you already have. The third uses the fact that removing $U\cap Y$ from $Y$ is the same as removing all of $U$ from $Y$, since anything in $U\setminus Y$ is irrelevant. And the fourth is just the fact that subtracting a set is the same as intersecting with its complement.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a\in A\Longrightarrow a\notin Y-A\Longrightarrow a\notin U\cap Y$. So that means, $a\notin U$ or $a\notin Y$. But $a\in A\subseteq Y$, so the only possibility is $a\notin U$. Thus $a\in Y\cap (X-U) $.

Conversely, take $a\in Y\cap (X-U)\Longrightarrow a \in Y$ and $a\notin U\Longrightarrow a \notin Y \cap U=Y-A \Longrightarrow a \in A$.